# NestJS Typeorm save one to many relationship

Tags: mysql, typescript, nestjs, one-to-many, typeorm

I am trying to save an array of objects within my nestjs project in a one to many relationship.

The frontend gives me something like this to work with:

```
[
{
"actor":"actorname",
"role":"actorrole"
},
{
"actor":"actorname2",
"role":"actorrole2"
}
]
```

in order to save all those I created a movie entity and an actor entity like this:

actor.entity.ts

```js
//imports
@Entity()
export class Actor {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @ManyToOne(() => Movie, (movie) => movie.actors)
    movieId: number;

    @Column()
    role: string;

    @Column()
    actor: string;
}
```

movie.entity.ts

```js
//imports
@Entity()
export class Movie {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    //more stuff

    @OneToMany(() => Actor, (actor) => actor.movieId)
    actors: Actor[];
}
```

the issue now is, my frontend is returning the JSON data as a whole string, so I have to `JSON.parse()` it first and accept it within my dto like this:

```js
//imports
export class CreateMovieDto {
    actorsArray: string;
}
```

now my problem is saving the json data

```js
//imports
@EntityRepository(Movie)
export class MoviesRepository extends Repository<Movie> {
    async createMovie(
        createMovieDto: CreateMovieDto,
        fileName: string,
        filePath: string,
    ) {
        const movie = this.create(createMovieDto);

        let actorsArray = JSON.parse(createMovieDto.actorsArray);
        //how do i save it now together with the movie?
        
        try {
            //await this.save(movie); disabled for now
            return movie;
        } catch (error) {
            if ((error.code = 'ER_DUP_ENTRY')) {
                console.log(error);
                throw new ConflictException('Movie already exists');
            } else {
                console.log(error);
                throw new InternalServerErrorException();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should do something like this

//how do i save it now together with the movie?

```
    const actorsEntities = await Promise.all( actorsArray.map(async (actor) => {
        const actorEntity = new Actor(actor);
    
        // Save the image entity to the database
        await this.actorsRepository.save(actorEntity);
    
        return actorEntity
     }));

      );
    movie.actors = actorsEntities;
    this.save(movie);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As far as i know, an entity instance doesn't accept params. So you need to do `new Actor()`, assign properties `actorEntity.foo = "bar"` and then you can save.
You may check docs on Repository API, `create()` section (there's a code comment about this) https://typeorm.io/repository-api or again https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/README#using-repositories